# Face Detection algorithm is not working if I click a snap from landscape mode

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, ios4

I have used the below code to detect face from an image:

```
-(void)markFaces:(UIImageView *)imagePick {

CIImage* image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:imagePick.image.CGImage];
CIDetector* detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace 
                                          context:nil options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh forKey:CIDetectorAccuracy]];
NSDictionary* imageOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:6] forKey:CIDetectorImageOrientation];
NSLog(@"imageOptions %@",imageOptions);
NSArray* features = [detector featuresInImage:image options:imageOptions];

if([features count] > 0)
{
    NSLog(@"Face Found");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Face not Found");        
}
}
```

and this algorithm is not working if I click a snap from landscape mode. Why? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Does it work for images taken in portrait upside down mode (home button on top). You can try rotating capture image by applying a transform..

Comment: Have a look on it 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496724/how-to-develop-a-face-recognition-iphone-app/10497002#10497002
it may help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
NSDictionary* imageOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:6] forKey:CIDetectorImageOrientation];
```

You are actually telling it to look for portrait orientations only as the number you are passing is 6.

The documentation in the header file says that:

> // Options that can be used with -[CIDetector featuresInImage:options:]
>
> /* The value for this key is an integer NSNumber from 1..8 such as that
>    found in kCGImagePropertyOrientation.  If present, the detection will be done
>    based on that orientation but the coordinates in the returned features will
>    still be based on those of the image. */

And the options are

[image]

It's annoying that `featuresInImage:options:` is not documented (I'll have to file a bug now that I've seen it)

Comment: Okay, Thank u and i too found that also.